# How to loading indicator in angular service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I need to make something that will show to user that ajax request is still being executed.

I have an angular module:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngCookies',
    'localization',
    'myControllers',
    'myServices'
]);
```

My service looks like:

```
var myServices = angular.module('myServices', ['ngResource']);
myServices.factory('MyInfo', ['$resource',function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/:method', {}, {
        getSettings: {method:'POST', params:{method:'get_my_settings'}},
        getInfo: {method:'POST',params:{method:'get_my_info'}}
    });
}]);
```

And my controller:

```
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);
myControllers.controller('someCtrl', ['$scope', 'MyInfo',
   function($scope, MyInfo) {
      $scope.myInfo = MyInfo.getInfo();
   }
]);
```

Everything works fine! But how can I start doing some action before sending request and finish this action when request is complete and response was received?

ajax in jquery has parameters "beforeSend" and "complete" where you can define what to do before send and when request complete.

How to do it in angular?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Angular give you access to the `$http` module which have a `pendingRequests` property.

See for example : https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/services/httpRequestTracker.js

They're creating a service :

```
angular.module('services.httpRequestTracker', [])

.factory('httpRequestTracker', ['$http',
    function($http) {

        var httpRequestTracker = {};
        httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests = function() {
            return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
        };

        return httpRequestTracker;
    }
])
```

Then you can now create a directive for showing an ajax loader (or anything else) when this service returns a pending request :

```
angular.module('directives.ajaxLoader', [
    'services.httpRequestTracker'
])

.directive('ajaxLoader', ['httpRequestTracker',
    function(httpRequestTracker) {
        return {
            templateUrl: 'common/ajaxLoader.tpl.html',
            restrict: 'EA',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            link: function($scope) { // This function can have more parameters after $scope, $element, $attrs, $controller
                $scope.hasPendingRequests = function() {
                    return httpRequestTracker.hasPendingRequests();
                };
            }
        };
    }
])
```

ajaxLoader.tpl.html :

```
<div class="fade" ng-class="{in: hasPendingRequests(), out: !hasPendingRequests()}">
    LOADING ...
</div>
```

Hope this helps